# RDBMS or NoSQL for complex schedule data with loops and ordered actions?

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql, database, nosql

I'm trying to figure out how best to store (and model) the scheduling component of an automation system.  I need to store schedules on which things will be executed (lights, pumps, etc.).  I'm not trying to managing the state of the schedule as it executes, yet.  For now I'm interested in how to store and let the user work with schedule creation.

I have not determined what to use to store the data (RDBMS, MongoDB, Cassandra, etc., etc.).  I think I'd prefer an RDBMS because much of the other data relational-like and I want to take advantage of joins, transactions, and be confident of the data resiliency.  I'm aware that RDBMSs are not the only game in town that gives me those but the majority of my experience is with SQL and recently a MongoDB project.  That said, I'm finding it difficult to describe the model in terms of tables and relationships.  Something like the below is what I have so far.

What would be the best storage method, and second to that, any tips on a workable model would be appreciated.

Some needs

- loops of actions
- order of execution
- transactions a big plus

Example Schedule

```
1) [step1] [action] room 1 lights on
2) [step2] [loop] 5x
    2.1 [step2.1] [action] tv on  (ignoring duration of steps)
    2.2 [step2.2] [action] tv off
3) [step3] [action] pool pump on
```

Answer (score 0):

In any reasonably complex automation system I think you'll find that you really need [a state machine](http://blog.abodit.com/2012/07/updated-release-abodit-state-machine/) and [a way to store state](http://blog.abodit.com/2013/02/variablewithhistory-making-persistence-invisible-making-history-visible/).

Storing state is fairly easy; storing the state machine and executing it is not so easy.  One approach is to define the state machine in code and have it calculate the next time it needs to execute, you then put a record in the database for that next execution time. Your main loop then simply pulls events from the database in order, waits until it has one due for execution, loads the appropriate state machine and executes it. During execution the state machine can change the state of any variable (including external devices on/off state) and can re-schedule itself for execution one or more times in the event list.

I linked a couple of blog posts describing the way my automation system works. My requirements are a lot more complex that simple timing loops; they involve conditional logic, logic based on the history of what has happened previously and such like, but I suspect that sooner or later you will want to move beyond simple loops.

Comment: Ian, I think your comment is spot on for the execution logic.  I probably didn't make my question clear, but at the moment I am working on the experience for creating and managing the schedule.  So I expect I will be interrogating the schedule data, which is like an interface, and exploding it into an event/state model, as a next step.